# Regex with WinAutomation

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to use an expression in WinAutomation to extract the state code (WA) from an address. WinAuto uses the .NET flavor of Regex

Example address

```
18890 8th Ave NE
Poulsbo, WA  98370-8770
United States
```

I tried using the following expression and even though it works fine in Regex101 and it shows that it selects just the state code, but it don't work the same within WinAuto

`\w+(?=\s\s)` - [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/9NOXKm/1)

In Winauto, the above expression fetches the following

```
NE 8770
```

Whereas the desired output with the expression is just the state code, WA

Please advise

Comment: Try replacing each `\s` with a regular space.

Comment: It then returns an empty value

Comment: that pattern couldn't possibly match a space.  you sure it isn't something else?

Comment: This is the page where I am trying to extract the address out of - https://www.mywsba.org/LawyerDirectory/LawyerProfile.aspx?Usr_ID=11917

Comment: I'm really confused now from your question. Please edit it and clarify: what is the input of your regex?  What should be the result? Identifying address from a bunch of text is much more complicated then just a simple regex

Comment: Hi Máté - sorry about the confusion, I have edited the question to add more details. What I am looking for is to just extract the state code from the address above, which is WA. When I use the expression `\w+(?=\s\s)` in regex101 to test, the output is perfect (the state code only) but when I enter the same expression in WinAutomation, the output is `NE 8770`. Hope this clarifies. Please let me know if you need any further information

Comment: This has been solved. Posted the answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this has been resolved. The problem was the way the address was showing up on the webpage (with line breaks) is different from the way it was showing up within WinAutomation (without line breaks). So the original expression wasn't working.

I have revised the expression to `\w{2}(?=\s\d{1,5}-\d{1,5})` and it now works perfectly

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/YsYyL3/1/)